# Calling a method from another class. error : No visible @interface ... declares the selector

Tags: objective-c

I have two classes *DetailViewController* and *Substitution*, I would use the Substitution class methods but I get this error:

No visible @interface "Substitutions" declares the selector "Crypt ::"

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "Substitutions.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tvC;

- (IBAction)bCrypter:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Substitutions * s;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize s;
@synthesize tvC;

- (IBAction)bCrypter:(id)sender
{
    s = [[Substitutions alloc]init];
    [s Crypter:tvC.text :1]; <-- No visible @interface "Substitutions" declares the selector "Crypter::" 
    //NSLog(@"%@",tvC.text);   
}
```

**Substitutions.h**

```
@interface Substitutions : NSObject

+ (NSString*)Crypter:(NSString*)msg :(id)cles;

@end
```

**Substitutions.m**

```
#import "Substitutions.h"

@implementation Substitutions


+ (NSString*)Crypter:(NSString*)msg :(id)cles
{
    NSLog(@"%@",msg);
    return @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Crypter` is class method not instance method so you should call directly with class name not need to create instance for call method.

Ex.

```
[Substitutions Crypter:tvC.text :1];
```

Comment: or change the method from `+ (NSString*)Crypter...` to `- (NSString*)Crypter...`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and for help